# Voronoi diagrams in Matlab: Specifying upper limit on number of edges of cells

Tags: matlab, voronoi, topology

I need to create a Voronoi diagram which will be eventually used in a separate code. This separate code can handle polygons upto n=6 (Hexagons) only.

Does the Matlab provide capability of specifying an upper limit on number of edges that a Voronoi cell can contain? Or, is there a roundabout way of specifying the edge limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such possibility because it goes against the definition of Voronoi diagrams and, more generally, it makes no sense.

Voronoi diagram have a precise definition that allows to have polygonal cells with any number of edges above a minimal number that depends on the space dimension. If you constrain the maximum number of edges, then you are not doing a Voronoi tesselation anymore. So there is no reason to implement that feature in the `voronoi` function.

Then, if we assume you talk about the two-dimensional case, Euler's theorem states that the average number of edges per cell has to be 6. If you forbid cells to have *more* than 6 edges, then to satisfy the average=6 constraint you also have to forbid cells having *less* than 6 edges, and thus allow only cells with *exactly* 6 edges.

You have then to define how to apply this constraint in your tesselating algorithm, and this is extremely complex, if not impossible. This is why this feature is not implemented elsewhere.

I strongly suggest you examine other options than using a software that can deal only with a small subset of all possibilities and/or non-Voronoi tesselation.